# How to generate a graph from reading numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, graph

I know that there are several ways to graph using APIs in Python. But let's say I have the following code:

```
from random import randint
i = 1
while i < 1000:
     num = randint(0,9)
     print num
     // Add num to a graph that is Random Number versus Time
// Show graph
```

What should I do such that I can generate a graph that has Random numbers (from 0->9) versus Time.

Comment: You need to add code showing what you have tried to graph, as there are a number of ways, and graphs, to do this depending on the requirements and level of visualization quality one is looking for. I mean if you put the numbers and times in a list a quick `plt.bar(numbers, times)` would give you a sorta histogram using matplotlib.

Answer (score 4):

Following your code (changing 1000 to 100 for a clearer plot), you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import randint
i = 1
numbers = [0]*100
while i < 100:
     numbers[i] = randint(0,9)
     i += 1
plt.plot(np.arange(1,101),numbers, 'o')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: + import numpy as np

Comment: @pmod Thanks, added the missing import statement.